# Symfony routing based on host

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'd like to define a route 'product_page' which will map to different patterns based on the host.  The patterns for each route will be different, but I'd like for the route name to be the same so that I can use the same name in my console commands when generating URLs via the route (based on passed host name).  I cannot figure out how to make this happen, since it seems that routes of the same name overwrite previous routes.  For example:

```
product_page:
    pattern:  /product_page_type_1/{id}
    host: domain1.com
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index}
    requirements:
        id: '[\d]+'

product_page:
    pattern:  /product_page_type_2/{id}
    host: domain2.com
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index}
    requirements:
        id: '[\d]+'
```

Then, in my console command, I'd like to generate a URL based on the product_page route and host.  For example:

```
//should equal http://domain1.com/product_page_type_1/999
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('product_page', array('id' => 99, 'host' => 'domain1.com'), UrlGenerator::ABSOLUTE_URL)

//should equal http://domain2.com/product_page_type_2/999
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('product_page', array('id' => 99, 'host' => 'domain2.com'), UrlGenerator::ABSOLUTE_URL)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your second route is overwriting the first route. They shouldn't be named the same, just name them: `domain1_product_page` and `domain2_product_page` or something similar.

Comment: But if I'm in a console command, I want to be able to use the same route name but only change the host.  Would I have to change all my routes to have the domain name as part of them? Like product_page_domain1.com and product_page_domain2.com?

Comment: Yes, you will have to